# C# association with xaml

Tags: c#, class, xaml, arraylist, associations

I am trying to make an enroll/withdraw student into course project however I am not entirely sure how to add specific students to specific course.

I have a Course and Student class, and then a xaml window with a combobox, and list box with appropriate buttons.
When I press the enrol right now it simply takes the selected student and adds it into the "EnrolledStudents" text box to display the name however it doesn't actually assign it to the selected Course.

Code I have so far:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Course bsc = new Course("BSc(Hons) Applied Computing");
    Course hnd = new Course("Higher National Diploma (HND) Applied Computing");
    Course partTime = new Course("Computer Science Part Time (MSc)");

    Student andy = new Student("Andy", "Watt");
    Student dave = new Student("Dave","Newbold");
    Student daniel = new Student("Daniel","Brown");

    lbCourses.Items.Add(bsc);
    lbCourses.Items.Add(hnd);
    lbCourses.Items.Add(partTime);

    cbStudents.Items.Add(andy);
    cbStudents.Items.Add(dave);
    cbStudents.Items.Add(daniel);              
}
```

and the enroll button click code:

```
private void butEnroleStudent_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    cbStudents.SelectedItem.ToString();
    lbEnroledStudents.Items.Add(cbStudents.SelectedItem);
}
```

but I am not sure where to go from here. My main issue is I don't know how to select the Student and Course instead of the string values.

Comment: Would you consider using MVVM instead of this direct UI manipulation? Its *way* easier when it comes to stuff like this...

Answer (score 0):

As BradleyDotNET suggests, MVVM would be a lot easier for you to use, especially if your UI is going to get a lot more complicated. Also, any application like this is most likely going to rely on a database behind the scenes and hence you would be looking to bind all of your data controls.

That said, here is a sample that would achieve what you are trying to do there.

Presuming your `Student` class looks something like this:

```
private class Student
{
    public String FirstName { get; set; }
    public String Surname { get; set; }

    public Student(String firstName, String surname)
    {
        FirstName = firstName;
        Surname = surname;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return FirstName + " " + Surname;
    }
}
```

And your `Course` class something like this:

```
private class Course
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public List<Student> EnrolledStudents { get; set; }

    public Course(String name)
    {
       Name = name;
       EnrolledStudents = new List<Student>();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
       return Name;
    }
}
```

(Note that I have added a `List` to store the students enrolled on the given course)

Rather than adding to the `Items` property of your `ListBox` and `ComboBox` create collections that we can bind to:

```
private List<Student> _students;
private List<Course> _courses;
```

Constructing your test data then looks like this:

```
_courses = new List<Course>();
_courses.Add(new Course("BSc(Hons) Applied Computing"));
_courses.Add(new Course("Higher National Diploma (HND) Applied Computing"));
_courses.Add(new Course("Computer Science Part Time (MSc)"));

_students = new List<Student>();
_students.Add(new Student("Andy", "Watt"));
_students.Add(new Student("Dave", "Newbold"));
_students.Add(new Student("Daniel", "Brown"));

lbCourses.ItemsSource = _courses;
cbStudents.ItemsSource = _students;
```

Then when you click your enroll button

```
private void butEnroleStudent_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (lbCourses.SelectedIndex >= 0 && cbStudents.SelectedIndex >= 0)
    {
        // Both a student and course are selected
        Course selectedCourse = (Course)lbCourses.SelectedItem;
        Student studentToAdd = (Student)cbStudents.SelectedItem;
        if (!selectedCourse.EnrolledStudents.Contains(studentToAdd))
        {
           // Course does not already contain student, add them
           selectedCourse.EnrolledStudents.Add(studentToAdd);
           lbEnroledStudents.Items.Refresh();
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, to show the enrolled students in `lbEnroledStudents` as you click through the courses, you will need to hook up a new event handler in the xaml:

```
<ListBox x:Name="lbCourses" SelectionChanged="lbCourses_SelectionChanged"></ListBox>
```

And in the code behind:

```
private void lbCourses_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Course selectedCourse = (Course)lbCourses.SelectedItem;
    lbEnroledStudents.ItemsSource = selectedCourse.EnrolledStudents;
}
```